# Windows 8.1 App - HttpWebRequest working only once

Tags: web-services, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, winrt-async

I've a problem with my simple windows store app.

I'm connecting to SharePoint and query his REST services to get the information I need. Actually I'd like to create a sort of "SharePoint Browser" so that a user can navigate the List structure of SharePoint browsing with the APP.

Actually I get the security token from SharePoint and use it in all the calls without any problem.

My call is something like:

```
var bldr = new UriBuilder(_uri.ToString());
bldr.Path += _listDataSvc + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? String.Empty : "/" + path);  
var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(bldr.Uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

This gives me back what I need.. But only once! If I get this data, show them to the user and the user performs an action that calls again the same procedure, the system stucks in the GetResponseAsync() and throws no exception or other.

The system works in the same way even if I use the same Cookie and URL...

What could be the problem? I try to find out with fiddler but everything is in HTTPS, so I can see the app is sending the request again but receives no answer at all.

Comment: What exceptions are being thrown? From where? Have you tried using HttpClient instead?

Comment: No exception at all.. Simply the "await" takes so much time that the application crash..

Comment: You should look into the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient) class from WinRT (Windows.Web.Http namespace). That is the preferred method to do web requests on Windows 8.1. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761504.aspx) and [here](http://kraigbrockschmidt.com/blog/?p=963).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out where the problem was:

somewhere in the code I was using instructions like:

var x = request.GetResponseAsync().Result;

instead of:

var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

Having a lot of calls, the system reaches a sort of deadlock status because every other WebService call was waiting for the previous one.